# Restarting deployments that are defined in subcharts in a master chart

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to automate the deployment of my dockerized app in kubernetes with GitLab CI/CD. I use Helm for Kubernetes to deploy multiple instances of my app (for different clients). These instances all have different database credentials and tables.

masterchart Chart.yaml

```yaml
dependencies:
- name: my_subchart
  version: "0.1.0"
  repository: "file://../my_subchart/"
  alias: my_subchart_a
- name: my_subchart
  version: "0.1.0"
  repository: "file://../my_subchart/"
  alias: my_subchart_
```

masterchart values.yaml

```yaml
my_subchart_a:
    my:
      config:
        database:
          dbhost: database.example.com
          dbname: database1
          dbuser: dbuser1
          dbpassword: password1
my_subchart_b:
    my:
      config:
        database:
          dbhost: database.example.com
          dbname: database2
          dbuser: dbuser2
          dbpassword: password2
```

These values in the master chart override the values in the specific subcharts. Both sub-charts use different database tables and users.

subchart values.yaml

```yaml
my:
  config:
    database:
      connection: mysql
      dbhost:
      port: 20506
      dbname:
      dbuser:
      dbpassword:
```

The sub-chart has a template of a deployment of my app. It pulls the image myimage:latest of my GitLab repository.

My GitLab lint builds a docker image of my app and pushes it to the GitLab registry to myimage:latest. Then, I would like to add something to my GitLab CICD that refreshes all the deployments that are made with the subcharts. Now I manually have to do `kubectl rollout restart deployment <deployment1>` (for every subchart deployment).

Is there a way to restart all deployments that are defined in my helm master chart?

Comment: If you use a unique tag per build (not `latest`) Kubernetes will restart things for you.  You can have your CD system pass the tag in as a Helm value.

Comment: What would be the command to use to do this? `helm upgrade --set image=newimage myrelease mychart` can't be used since the chart isnt available on my git (for security reasons).

Comment: Also, how would you upgrade all the subcharts with one command? For scalability reasons

Comment: I would use exactly `helm upgrade`.  You can pass it a local `./charts/mychart` path the same way you did with `helm install`.  That will upgrade all of the subcharts (in fact, you don't have a choice on that).

Comment: @Jurjen Have you managed to make it work?